# radio button async posting

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

Parameters are
Http request Parameters are given below.

```
__ASYNCPOST=true
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$MainContent$dlReportType$ctl01$rdbtnReportType   
__EVENTVALIDATION=${EventValidation}    
__VIEWSTATE=${Viewstate}    
ctl00$MainContent$ScriptManager1=ctl00$MainContent$upnlReportType|ctl00$MainContent$dlReportType$ctl01$rdbtnReportType    
ctl00$MainContent$dlReportType$ctl01$rdbtnReportType=rdbtnReportType   
ctl00$MainContent$hdnItemID=${ItemID}
ctl00$MainContent$hdnItemTypeID=1
```

which is not working
Response i am getting from the server is

> 1|#||4|53|pageRedirect||%2fsitename%2fCommon%2fErrorPages%2fError.aspx|

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Highlighted the response .

Answer (score 0):

validate you are capturing View state and Event Validation from correct response and also try to enable encoding check box beside the mentioed Name-Value pair because sometimes Jmeter accepts encoded values

Comment: Viewstate and event validations are double checked.And encoded the request too.Still same response from server